# Does asking for a technical standard constitute a software recommendation?

Tags: discussion, scope, software-recs-se

I'm new to meta so please excuse any "breaking of rules"! This question of mine: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511997/json-schema-for-css-properties was recently put **on hold**.

Now I get the rules for *Software Recommendations* like

*what is the best tool to handle events?*, or

*which is **the best** syntax highlighter*.

These will clearly give **opinion based** answers and not a factual one. I assume the rationale of this rules was that there is **no right answer** for such questions and there is a potential for abusive advertising of software tools / libraries etc.

In this question, I specifically ask for a JSON encoding of the W3C standard for CSS. This is a software standard, ratified by a standards body. **There are no opinionated answers** on this because I am asking for  **a fact** (in a way).

Either its right or wrong, quite objective. Kindly assist me in either taking the **on hold** off of the answer or giving a rational explanation of how it falls under **Software Recommendation**.

If we go with the former, this meta question would be useful for other such questions that deal with standards and clearing up Stack Exchange's policy over it!

Comment: The off-topic flag explanation reads: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic [...] and "an existing implementation of a JSON-Schema" is an off-site resource.

Comment: note: requests for official documentation are allowed. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417732/11107541

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see two problem statements in your question that justify the close reason:

> I was wondering if there is an existing implementation

This is asking for an library, which is mentioned in the close reason. Answers will most likely be link-only answers which are bad.

> I am asking for a definitive document that covers the CSS standard.

Here you are again asking for an off-site resource. Or did you want us to copy/paste the entire document here? Of course not. This question is off-topic.