# Overhauling our community's closure reasons and guidance

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

### Overview

As we know Stack Overflow has a closure process which users begin participating in at 15 reputation with [flagging privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) and then later with full closure votes at [3000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

Recently, I've been thinking a lot about our closure reasons/guidance, and if they actually do what they set out to do.

What initially started me thinking about our closure reason's was [Cody Gray's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412865) to [Make description of “community-specific reason” close reason more clear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412863) in which a complete revamp of closure reasons was proposed.

### Discovery

Over the past several months, I've continued to think about how we use our closure reasons, and where we can potentially have room for improvement.

I've also found more than a few related discussions, so it's clear that there are changes that the community is interested in making, but very few are making it to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed):

- [Avoiding overly specific site referrals for general computing and sysadmin questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313264)
- [Remove the mention of "Super User" from the standard off-topic close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872)
- [Change the 'general computing hardware and software' off topic reason to one that clearly describes the 'write code for me' questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288989)
- [Please add "tutorials" back to the off-site close reason text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415884)
- [Make description of “community-specific reason” close reason more clear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412863)
- [Put a direct link to the MCVE/MRE help page on the closure notice for "needs debugging details"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397048)
- [Off-topic option: include Unix and Apple sister sites on off-topic notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380370)

In my exploration, I've learned that we really don't have much ability to affect change on the universal/network-wide closure reasons:

1. Duplicate
2. Needs detail or clarity
3. Needs more focus
4. Opinion-based
5. A community-specific reason

   - This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
   - Other - add a comment

If my understanding is correct, changing these reasons would have widespread effects throughout the network and also require dev time to complete.

However, I've also learned that we *do* have several reasons that are modifiable with [CM controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIKCP.png). These are likely things that we would be able to change if we could come together with a consensus of how we want these to be.

### Our 5 Community-Specific Closure Reasons:

Something I had vaguely been aware of, but had not fully conceptualised is that there are [5 configurable fields](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362584):

> 1. Brief description
> 2. Usage guidance
> 3. Post notice close description
> 4. Post owner guidance
> 5. Privileged user guidance

The current close descriptions read as follows:

1. About general computing hardware and software
2. About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration
3. Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
4. Needs debugging details
5. Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more

The full details for our current reasons are accessible [via SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1573733/current-close-reason-guidance)

### Process

Per [Catija's sample process on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362584)  I'd like to eventually be able to

> workshop the five fields for each (probably one meta discussion for each close reason)

But first I'd like to propose we **start with a community review of our existing community-specific closure reasons**, and consider which reasons we'd like to keep and those we'd like to retire.

Once we've established which reasons we are keeping, retiring, or adding we can then move on to workshopping each reason to nail down how we'd like the description and guidance to read. Then ultimately have the changes applied and improve the process for everyone involved.

Comment: I still don't understand the benefit of *"Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"* - It's just Opinion-Based but more specific

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine that reason evolved from *recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource* that at least mentioned *off-site resource* so you could distinguish between one opinion vs the other. From there on only more welcoming variants emerged.

Comment: @rene Yes, I can remember the old reason, and while the specificity it provided then made it more more clear than it is now, I'm not convinced it was distinct enough to be it's own close reason.

Comment: My thoughts are articulated here on this: [the closure system is outdated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396018/1026459).

Comment: Try providing a way for the person asking to question to request clarification on why their question has been closed. Unfortunately downvotes are a great tool for bully's as they are anonymous but closing a question should be very transparent.

Comment: Closure *is* already transparent, @dannyhut. Users closing are publicly visible, as well as the reason for closure. If one needs clarifications, there is a proper way to do so - posting a question on Meta tagged [meta-tag:specific-question].

Comment: @Oleg Valter is with Ukraine Thanks for the info can you tell me how to find out the User who closed the Question and where I find why my question has been closed. I can find no answer to these question with the closure notice.

Comment: @dannyhut If you have a question about why one of your own questions was closed you can [ask a separate question](/questions/ask) here on Meta to get feedback about your specific situation. _This_ post is about updating or modifying Stack Overflow’s existing site-specific closure reasons and _not_ about how the current reasons are used or about why any specific question was closed.

Comment: @Henry Ecker. My comment was in response to Oleg's comment. I am asking Oleg for clarification in response to his comment. I was not asking a question about any question I have asked, though I do see how you could assume I had.

Comment: All the information is in the post close notice at the top of the post. In your case it is "This question needs to be more focused" with a link to what closure, including "too broad" means. You can also inspect [the guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/417486#417486) we just published as part of this project for more details. Users who voted to close should be visible in the notice as well. IIRC the company changed that for users who *don't* have the close vote privilege, but they should still be visible in the post timeline.

Comment: The individuals who closed the post are never visible in the post notice if you’re the post owner @OlegValteriswithUkraine though they are, of course, listed in the timeline for everyone (even users without an account).

Comment: @HenryEcker if I recall correctly, that wasn't always the case, but yeah, it [was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/786798) for question authors alongside the removal of the user list for users without the CV/RV privilege.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine the reason for closure could be different for each close voter - it's not at all clear which one is picked by SO as the one to display.

Comment: I always wonder what the difference between "detail" and "focus" is. Aren't these two at least related? Adding detail to a broad question typically narrows it down, doesn't it?

Comment: @ThomasWeller the devil is in the details. Depending on what you add, you can broad the scope of the question or narrow it down.

Comment: There still exists a need to be able to [*change* the close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262657/why-cant-we-change-our-close-vote-reason) either becuase a different reason comes through an edit, or because of a mistake. It's very unforgiving.

Comment: ...a frequent situation is where detail has been added, and a duplicte becomes obvious, but it's too late. It's withdraw or nothing.

Comment: There are no legitimate reasons to close questions.

Comment: @sgfit Spam, (too much) Trolling, Harassment are.

Comment: @sgfit [Yes, there are.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: Related sub-question... why are we limited to three community-close reasons?    This whole thing might be somewhat alleviated by allowing 5 or 10 or "as many as required"

Comment: The current Stack Overflow limit is five (2 more than the network default of 3) and we are [currently] using all 5 of them. It is possible to increase this limit, but we'd need to [ask for new slots one at a time](/a/418166/15497888)

Answer (score 133):

Close reasons which I'm missing, that do not currently exist:

- **The question is not written in English.**

  This is very common.
- **Not a question but a copy/paste of a homework assignment.**

  Extremely common and very rude. Should optionally lead to disciplinary actions against the poster.
- **The question must demonstrate a minimum of knowledge/research about the topic being discussed.**

  We had this one until 2014 somewhere, when the site was still for professional and enthusiast programmers. A programmer being someone who has at least basic knowledge of the programming language in question. Which can be specifically defined as: having read the first chapters of a beginner-level book on the topic.

  Contrary to popular belief, SO is not an interactive beginner tutorial. It is not a replacement for conventional studies. The purpose of the site is not to give answers which can easily be found in the first chapter of a beginner-level book. Or through a brief search with an Internet search engine ("let me Google that for you").

  And before someone makes an argument that the "unclear" close reason should be used: no, the question isn't unclear at all. We simply expect the OP to put a minimum of effort into answering the question themselves before posting here. Questions completely lacking research cannot get edited into shape by providing a clarification.

Comment: Big upvote from me for _demonstrate minimum of knowledge/research_!

Comment: The third point is probably looking for the analogous to ServerFaul's "Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault."

Comment: *"The purpose of the site is not to give answers which can easily be found in the first chapter of a beginner-level book. Or through a brief search with an Internet search engine ("let me Google that for you")."* This is wrong. See the [tour], wherein it is noted that our goal is to build a library of high-quality answers to *every* question about programming. There is no requirement that a question not be too basic. That is not, and has never been, a close reason. [**"You are conflating three different forms of 'effort'"**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909).

Comment: @CodyGray Opinions cannot be right or wrong, that's not how discussions work. One purpose of meta is to decide what site the community wishes to have. I can't blame you for not remembering the "must demonstrate a minimum knowledge" close reason since it was removed by the company some 8 years back, though not through community consensus. It was there though, pretty much since the site was launched. Back in the days the ambition was to create a site useful for programmers and not for students with homework problems in order to gain maximum traffic.

Comment: Neither demonstrated effort nor non-beginner is required. The real problem is that such mega duplicate (or unanswerable) questions are not immediately closed as duplicates. The opposite happens: They are answered instead and there isn't *any* effort to find the duplicate. There ought to be some real risk of knowingly answering blatantly duplicate questions.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes and since digging up duplicates is more effort than answering the question, the same boring chapter 1 beginner questions get asked and answered over and over again. One problem is that SO's duplicate system is so bad, but we've asked for a better one for as long as anyone can remember and evidently it ain't gonna happen. This is a quick solution in the meantime. I agree that the rep farmers who keep answering over and over even though a well-known duplicate exists are a big problem - it could perhaps partially be solved by weighing down-votes as heavy as up-votes.

Comment: @CodyGray this site audience is "professional or enthusiast programmers", I don't think those kind of questions is what such audience would want.

Comment: No-one is trying to learn to program by just asking questions on SO. However people learning to program do get stuck on strange things that to you and me are blindingly obvious.  Why shouldn't they be able to ask questions about those things here? Equally EVERY question shows a lack of expertise at some level, every question could be answered by spending enough time with books and documentation. Setting some arbitrary bar of expertise below which we won't answer doesn't really make any sense to me.

Comment: It is (obviously) not in scope to add (or even consider adding) close reasons that conflict with the fundamental vision and purpose of the site. So, yes, contributions to a discussion can and will be pointed out as invalid, because they are based on wrong/flawed premises, and thus discounted entirely. Yes, I remember well the "lacks minimal understanding" close reason. It was never a "this question is too basic" close reason, and people abusing it for things like this and lack of "effort" is why the option was removed. There was strong community consensus. And it wasn't there at launch.

Comment: There is no "traffic" motivation for making the site useful to everyone; that's just utter fiction and revisionist history. Nor is there any truth to this oft-repeated saw that professional or enthusiast programmers wouldn't ask or be interested in basic questions. Everyone is a beginner at something. If I try to learn Ruby today, I would be a complete beginner, and having high-quality Q&A here about very basic stuff would be exceptionally useful to me, just as is having high-quality Q&A here about the complex stuff that I seek out on a regular basis for languages that I know better.

Comment: 'No-one is trying to learn to program by just asking questions on SO'.......do you wish examples of exactly that?   They are trivial to find:(

Comment: I mean, 'I have basically no knowledge of for loops' https://stackoverflow.com/q/71984742/758133. :((

Comment: @RichN No? Because I lost count of the "ask on SO instead of reading chapter 1 in a book" questions many years ago. It is not too much to ask of a would-be programmer to read chapter 1 in a beginner-level book. A large part of the programmer trade is about reading technical documentation.

Comment: @CodyGray Since the scope has changed over the years, we can change it back. [Introducing Stackoverflow.com]: "It is by programmers, for programmers, with the ultimate intent of collectively increasing the sum total of _good_ programming knowledge in the world." Answering some hundreds of "hello world" questions per day is not good or useful knowledge, it's spoon feeding of lazy kids who can't even bother to read chapter 1 in a beginner-level book.

Comment: SO has 'welcomized' the close reasons so that they no longer clearly represent questions that should surely be closed.  I have no intention of spending anything more than the absolute minimum of effort on questions where the poster has made a similar, minimum effort.  I will certainly not go looking for dupes or find links to 'Computer 101 week 1' sites.  Too many users are taking the piss, and I don't care about their 'feelings', whether real or, much more likely, just claimed.

Comment: @CodyGray "that conflict with the fundamental vision and purpose of the site" - which vision is that, exactly? The one of Jeff Atwood, which focused on a _high quality_ Q/A repository (e.g. "optimize for pearls not sand") and was abandoned a long time ago? The visions (rather, hallucinations) of "Team DAG" or more recent misguided approaches which went so well that the key people are not being employed by SO anymore? Or the vision of the CEO of the company which bought SO for billions and has a ficundiary duty to shareholders to extract that much value from the site?

Comment: @Lundin a technicality, the scope hasn't changed since the scope in [/help/on-topic](https://web.archive.org/web/20100628165146/http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is a thing, [circa 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182812/213575). The only thing that changed was adding and/ors. Some language came from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12373/213575), but it was in the FAQ already. Note, that there are earlier examples, but somehow many missed that it was "*programming questions*... of interest to other programmers", and programming on a boat happened.

Comment: Atwood and Spolsky's original vision, @l4mpi. At no point were beginner questions ever off-topic here. Nor, despite the straw men continually built in the comments, were duplicates, work orders, or non-questions ever on-topic. We're still "increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world" when we answer beginner-level questions. The amount of knowledge possessed by the asker is quite irrelevant, as long as they ask a question that can be answered in a Q&A format. We're still optimizing for pearls, not sand. Never have I claimed otherwise.

Comment: The "and/ors" @Braiam mentioned were added by Robert Harvey in May 2014. Clarification, not a scope change. So, again, this wasn't some conspiracy by the company to raise shareholder value, anything to do with the Summer of Love (which had nothing to do with topicality and everything to do with snarky comments), or any of the other ridiculous conspiracies trotted out in the comments here. Look, I get everyone's frustrated with actions the company's taken the past several years. I am, too. Probably more so, as a mod with greater exposure. But throwing this under that umbrella is just false.

Comment: @CodyGray The close reasons were silently changed by the company in 2014 here: [Recent changes to close reasons on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow). After which I protested both about the changed close reasons and the way they were silently changed without prior discussion with the community. To deaf ears.

Comment: Shog9 listed the rationale about the changes as "There were a handful of people who interpreted "minimal understanding" as a euphemism for "visible effort" or even "a wall of code"." As in requiring posting of unreasonable amounts of code and not really as something to do with minimum of knowledge required.

Comment: @CodyGray "We're still increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge" - a) we still get some decent Q/A pairs but we also bury existing knowledge under a trash heap and discoverability of information is a real issue (thus it's hard to say if the "knowledge value" of SO is going up or down), and b) we're also frustrating a lot of experts who don't want to wade through trash and either quit the site or heavily restricted their interactions with it. Just because there are still some good answers being added on SO doesn't mean the site is healthy or that the status quo can't be improved.

Comment: @CodyGray to TL;DR this whole discussion, many people have been fed up with garbage questions for years. The company line since the CR revamp linked by Lundin was always that "no effort" isn't directly corellated with "garbage question" because some zero-effort questions actually have value, thus there shouldn't be a "no effort" close reason as that might deprive us of a few decent questions. Ok, whatever, but we need an actual solution to the mountain of trash being dumped on SO daily, because that just makes the site worse for everyone - and nothing SO did so far worked.

Comment: Also... we were already quite frustrated with those trash questions back in 2014 and the quality of the site has eroded much further since then. Nobody has solved the problem in 8 years. Also note how in 2014 I could have a long dialogue in comments with an employed CM who took the time to at least respond even though I was obviously quite pissed off at the changes. I don't see that happening in 2022.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't see how what you say is different than what I said. I'm just expounding on the history of the scope of the site and how the current wording of the scope came to be, and that specific/unique and variations of thereof where always there. The scope hasn't changed, we just discovered their limits (and spawned several sites as result).

Comment: @CodyGray So in the company's opinion, there should be questions such as "How to make a conditional statement in {insert language}?" with the answer being "Use an `if` statement"... Is that really the point we want to descend to? That doesn't as much increase the sum total of good knowledge so much as completely bury actually useful knowledge (to any programmer who bothered to read a basic tutorial) under an obscene weight of useless questions (created by those who did not). Ultimately, [so] is simply not set up to create entire tutorials for languages.

Comment: There's already https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ which has the ambition to provide high quality beginners tutorials but in practice provides low quality ones. Although not nearly as bad as SO's "interactive beginner tutorials" (fragmented Q&A about utterly basic stuff). Learning a whole programming language by asking inane questions on SO about every single thing in the language doesn't seem like a very productive way of learning. Which of course won't prevent those questions from getting asked and answered anyway! SO making the Internet a slightly worse place, one question at a time.

Comment: The knowledge/research thing... I feel like the expectation here is that this'll be used to create some sort of minimal hurdle akin to the $1 that metafilter (used to?) charge for membership. The problem is... Close reasons don't act as a hurdle. Not for askers. Asking folks for research on the ask form would go a heck of a lot further in that regard.

Comment: @Shog9 I always believed that the best way to improve quality is if as many of the bad questions get caught before they even hit the site. Something for the "ask a question" revamp & wizard projects. And at some extent for automated scripts. But I don't think all those features can ever be made perfect, so we'll always have the need for manual moderation.

Comment: People can have their opinions of course, but trying to paint their gatekeeping away of beginner questions as somehow returning to "Jeff and Joel's original vision" is objectively false. Joel and Jeff have never said that beginner questions were not welcome or that they were necessarily low-quality.

Comment: Your first two are covered by the Unclear reason. Your last one is not a valid reason to close a question.

Comment: @TylerH The unclear reason could be made less unclear :) It doesn't hurt to be even more explicit regarding some of the most common close reasons.

Comment: The global downvote reason is "This question does not show research effort", and if a question attracts downvotes and no answers it is automatically closed **and deleted**. That there isn't an actual close reason for it makes no sense.

Comment: @OrangeDog That's a good point, especially since such down-voted and deleted posts will count towards the poster's automatic question ban. In theory someone could get a question ban without ever knowing why - just that "people down-voted your questions".

Comment: @CodyGray You said "work orders were *never* on-topic". What would be the appropriate close reason in that case? Let's say I need something done. I don't know how to code. I don't even want to frankenstein some code. What's stopping me from asking multiple parts of the "work order" as  multiple questions(divided just enough to not  qualify as "needs more focus"), getting specific answers from karma whores  and even asking a final question - "How to combine all this"? and changing some variable names and selling the finished product?

Comment: I agree with the two first points, but disagree with the last one. Questions that don't demonstrate any knowledge or research about the problem usually fall into two categories: (1) homework dumps and (2) questions of the type "I want to do <some common problem> but I have no idea where to start". Questions in (1) are already covered by your second point. Questions in (2) are often duplicates and can be closed as such, and when they aren't, they're often the first result when googling for how to do that, and are very useful and shouldn't be closed at all.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Often no duplicate exists simply because the question is so utterly basic, with zero research effort. "How does a for loop work in language x" and similar questions. You aren't meant to find the answer to such by googling, but by studying the most basic beginner material on the topic there is. As said in the answer: the purpose of SO is not to be an interactive beginner tutorial.

Answer (score 78):

Realized I was writing too much in the comments, so posting this as an answer. It addresses only one close reason:

> Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more

For context: the "recommendations" prohibition [originated as a warning against threads whose result would be inherently transient](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), - e.g. "what's the best perf/price for graphics cards".

It then picked up a more important use [as a tool against spam-honeypots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272519/should-every-recommendation-of-a-tool-by-its-owner-be-considered-spam), e.g. "what's the best package for charting?"

It then slowly morphed into its current state, with (sadly) a lot of that crucial context lost, leaving us where we are today: the description for the reason is simply,

> This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

...no mention of spam potential or even extremely transient (albeit fact-based) results. **No guidance on writing about a problem vs asking for a specific form of a solution!**

### Convergent evolution

Meanwhile, the "opinion-based" reason has moved in the other direction: it started out as a tool against what we used to call **flame-bait**, e.g. "What is the worst programming language and why is it Java?"; the reason was actually titled, "subjective *and argumentative*" for years.

But now it just talks about facts vs opinions. Which... Does seem to bring it *close* to the underlying rationale for "recommendations", but ... Sorta implicitly ascribes motives to the question author that are unlikely to exist for a true recommendation question.

### Taxonomy of bad questions vs guidance for good ones

Critically, the steps needed to make an "opinion" question (of the flame attracting sort) into a more constructive one are vastly different from those needed to turn a "recommendation" question (of [the X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) sort) into a problem statement.

THAT is the value of having a separate close reason, if we're to have one: [to offer specific guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254398/do-we-need-better-guidance-for-recommendation-questions), to closers, editors and askers, as to what a problematic question looks like and how it might be corrected.

If this reason is kept, we should strive to improve that guidance; if we cannot do so, it serves no purpose.

### Further reading

- [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)
- [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic)

Comment: Keeping in mind that I've read all of the "further reading" and know all of the context—do you have a concrete recommendation regarding the value of maintaining a separate, site-specific "recommendation question" close reason (putting aside from the moment how we might rewrite the guidance to make it better), instead of collapsing all of that into the network-wide "opinion-based" close reason? If I had free reign, I'd definitely collapse them. My only hesitation is that the network-wide "opinion-based" reason's guidance doesn't seem to be editable by us.

Comment: Well, that's one problem @cody; the other one is... The "reference" reason is [currently used a *lot* more than the "opinion" reason](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats).  There'd have to be a lot of adjustment. Also... We've been through this; back before we rolled out the site-specific reasons, I went through thousands of closed questions trying to figure out why they were closed based on context... It was crazy; there were sites that had their own *very* specific reasons for like one reason and didn't align with anything else. Imagine trying to explain this...

Comment: I could not agree more with your outlook on the opinionated closure reason. Productive yet slightly subjective material is critical to success here, and it is currently stifled. Decades worth of tested and proven expert opinion is being locked away.

Comment: As a thought experiment,... If one were considering rewording the opinion-based close reason, ... just out of curiosity... would you have recommendations for how we could do better? I've been struggling with the dilution of it for a while but I'm not sure that I've been able to adequately get to a non-accusatory close description that manages to avoid people closing questions that may be subjective but likely fall into "good subjective". That said, I think that having different guidance in the close modal vs the post notice goes a long way. The modal can be more direct.

Comment: Something like "not authoritatively answerable" might work, @Catija. It is indeed a big issue that we often cling to the "opinion" word and close posts for being subjective rather than for what this reason is intended for - preventing discussions with no way to tell if a given answer is objectively good or bad.

Comment: @Catija - imo opinionated needs to be fully remodeled. We want material which is based on specific expertise, however, often posts are closed which include any level of opinion. *"Opinion-based": This question is asking for general opinions. Edit the question to address facts, references, or specific expertise."*

Comment: I think you gotta start by asking, "what problem are we trying to solve?" and then ... Maybe asking if a close reason is the right solution at all, @Cat. I mean, the original reason... Well, back in the very early days there was a close reason for spam too; that got dropped in favor of a flag that makes ZERO effort to avoid finger-pointing. OTOH, a question that isn't straight-up flame-bait ... Maybe it doesn't need to be closed. Maybe it only needs to be closed *after* it attracts a pile of unsourced answers (and then you can point the finger at those answers).

Comment: Except that we're trying to stop the problem of a pile of unsourced, low-quality answers getting posted. Closing the door after the horse has already left the barn is hardly a compelling solution.

Comment: Then let's call a spade a spade, @Cody - maybe, "Mostly attracts uninformed opinons". That'd be a great fit for questions like [this one I pulled off the recent list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71797185), but not so much for questions that explicitly ask for sources (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71797618) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71755970)). FWIW, the software engineering site (due to its history as "Programmers") has had a pile of clear & specific reasons over its history aimed at various sorts of questions that inevitably garner uninformed opinions, speculation, etc.

Comment: Pretty much all advice on how to write code is a developer's opinion in some way on how to best write code to solve a problem.  And, we actually want educated and reasoned opinions.  So, I'm definitely in favor of nuking the word "opinion" entirely from the reasoning for closing a question and find a different way to describe whatever it is that you're trying to target.

Comment: @jfriend00 thing is that that reason is used elsewhere on the network, so it can be a bit more difficult to get everyone on board.

Comment: @Braiam - Now  you're referring to some process that I'm not a part of or aware of.  I'm just offering feedback that I don't think it's helpful to denigrate all "opinion" like this close reason does.

Comment: @jfriend00 I wish there is a process. There's none. The last several times that the network wide reasons were changed, it was done by SE without our input.

Answer (score 43):

> Not reproducible or was caused by a typo

This close reason currently contains two *unrelated* problems for which a given post may be closed. The "caused by a typo" part is relatively straightforward and intuitive to use whereas the "not reproducible" one clashes with the "needs debugging details" close reason (as community members failing to reproduce the problem is commonly *caused* by the lack of details about specific configuration / environment / browser / device, etc).

What we end up with is counter-intuitive: we use it to close questions with issues that are *obsolete* due to changes to the system / environment (most prominently used on Meta when certain features of the network are completely revamped or sunsetted). However, in many cases such questions are still answerable with pointers to sunset / deprecation schedules, as well as still be useful to those stuck with obsolete versions of services / software.

It is proposed that we return the reason to its *original* meaning and drop the "not reproducible" part. We [used to have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252034/where-did-too-localized-go) a more straightforward and intuitive wording for this reason: "too localized" (which can be further refined to "too specific" as this is exactly what it means: that the underlying issue is tightly coupled to the author's situation / code and is not helpful to anyone in slightly different circumstances).

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm not a developer but "too localized" and "Too specific" are neither particularly helpful to me to understand what they mean. If what you're saying is correct, why not expand on the "Needs debugging details" reason to allow for both... "This question can't be reproduced by others either because it lacks debugging details or relates to localized settings that aren't apparent to others. To improve this question, ... {explain what needs to be added to fix the issue}." Again, as I'm not a dev, this may all be nonsense, so feel free to tell me I'm silly. :D

Comment: Yes, not sure why they decided to change the wording in a way that would alter the meaning. [I actually brought this up two years ago when it was first changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396791/8967612) and suggested a slight amendment that would convey the original meaning but it was never picked up.

Comment: @41686d6564 That does seem like a vastly different thing, indeed - so, if someone says "*I asked this question but now I can't seem to get the same result - I don't know what I did to 'fix' it but :shrug:, I guess it's no longer relevant*"... assuming they don't delete the question themselves, this gives the closers a way to say "we don't know what happend or how this was fixed but we'll never know at this point so... let's move on to something else now."

Comment: @Catija - It isn't localized settings, it was worded that like that indicate that the question's usefulness would only be localized to the user asking. Debugging details are something entirely different, and specificity gets into asking for definitions. Expanding solely on debugging details would be detrimental, as we are already so narrowly painted into a corner for only helpdesking people's existing code that to go further would cause damage to the site.

Comment: @Catija you are silly :) Now, with the sanstioned pun out of the way, let's get to business: that's actually what I am thinking about - the primary meaning of "no repro" is that with the info provided is not sufficient, hence, yeah, "needs debugging details". As for the typo part, I think "too specific" explains well what this is about (too tightly coupled to the OPs code or situation), but not adamant on the wording. Imagine a user posting a question on a syntx error in their code - usually, it turns out they forgot a comma, a semi-colon, etc.

Comment: I think @Oleg makes a good point here, in that the close reasons need to be decoupled and distinct. Having them overlap only makes it harder on everyone as it introduces interpretation.

Comment: The thing is they shouldn't overlap @Travis. They never did until two years ago when the wording was changed. Before that, the "typo" reason wasn't being used to close "no repro" questions. Those types of questions have always been closed using the "no MCVE" reason (i.e., "Needs debugging details"). The "typo" reason is for problems that are _already resolved_ either by pointing out a simple syntax error (AKA, typo) or because the problem has "sorted itself out" for one reason or another. `No-repro != no longer reproducible`.

Comment: Before changing it to "Not reproducible or...", it used to say _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, **this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers**."_ I see that as something completely different from "Needs debugging details", so I'm against merging them. How would the question need debugging details if the problem has already been resolved? CC: @Catija

Comment: @Catija The two close reasons are different in terms of being actionable: *debugging details* means there is some information missing and *the OP should provide them* to make the Q answerable. For *typo/not reproducible* the question is clear but there is nothing the OP can do - there is just either no problem at all or it is extremely specific to just the OP. No amount of adding/changing details can salvage the latter.

Comment: The only confusion is that those were the causes that bought about as consqueuences the thing that @41686d6564standsw.Palestine puts in bold. The reason why we are closing it is later, not the former part. Maybe if we turn the whole message around: "This question was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers, it might be caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."

Comment: I propose that this close reason be rephrased to something like "no need to preserve for future readers". If a question was resolved by pointing out a trivial mistake (e.g. a typo, an invalid test, etc.) then generally the question gets closed with this reason. Such questions are about programming, are specific and answerable, and indeed do get answered (often in the comments), it's just that the answer will probably not be needed by anyone else so there is "no need to preserve" it.

Comment: The typo reason is also used for questions whose answer is not exactly a typo, but still a silly mistake on the part of the asker. "Why does my program stop at 10?" "Well you told it to stop at 10, see here" "Oh whoops, I had left that in from some testing. Thanks!" - the essence of "not helpful for future readers" still applies.

Answer (score 31):

I often find myself typing "[I’m voting to close this question because] it is not related to programming" in the "Other" field.

I would suggest merging "About general computing hardware and software" and "About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration" into a more general "Not about programming".

It would be great if it were possible to point at a specific site where  the question might be on topic, but that can always be done in a comment.

Comment: That (belongs on another-site) list of other Stack Exchange sites, and the question-migration feature that goes with it, should grow to include askubuntu.com, wordpress.stackexchange.com, and possibly some others (based on my limited question-answering experience).

Comment: I agree. Every time I vote to close because the question belongs on RaspberryPi Stack Exchange or Software Recs, I always ask myself why we can't have a full dropdown list all SE sites to choose from instead of the arbitrary and uselss 4-5 options.

Comment: Let's nip the "increase the migrate list" request in the bud. It ain't gonna happen; no one wants the leftover crap from Stack Overflow. We get too much junk that isn't on topic for any Stack Exchange site that no site in its collective right mind wants that crap after they've graduated. So, no, just because a question mentions Ubuntu or asks for a recommendation doesn't mean it's on topic for those sites, and unless you have a badge or twenty on those sites, they don't want the questions you're recommending.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree that voting for migration from the close dialog is a bad idea, and never use it. But what if it weren't a migration vote any more? You select a site from the dropdown and it puts a comment saying "your question *may* be on topic here, check the posting guidelines first, etc." and registers a CV.

Comment: @miken32 same issue. You are claiming something that isn't true. That the same question would be welcomed on the other site. Instead focus on this site, Stack Overflow, and tell them it's not appropriated here. If the asker is inclined to engage, they will figure out if there's somewhere they should ask (note that less than 5% of questions are ever edited once closed and less than that the asker engage with the feedback).

Answer (score 20):

This is long overdue for Stack Overflow. We don't need to tell users where their questions might be appropriate, just that it's not appropriate *here*. Both SU and SF close reasons made sense when those were the only sites, but there [are more](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Now we have a list [of potential comments directing users to other sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417484/792066), which are difficult to maintain instead of a simple single one for anyone, which doesn't require a site to exist. Below is my proposed guidance along with the text:

---

### A community-specific reason > Not unique to software development or programming-related

#### *"This question is not about programming"*

**How we define unique to software development or programming-related**

Questions have to be practical and unique to software development to be on-topic on Stack Overflow. This means that questions that are not practical programming tasks or tasks not intrinsic to software development should not be asked on Stack Overflow.

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

##### Before closing the question for this reason, consider the following:

Is the question on-topic on Stack Overflow? Being on-topic on another site of the network does not automatically make a question off-topic here. If the question is not on-topic on Stack Overflow:

- Consider whether the question should be migrated [to another site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) or closed as off-topic for Stack Overflow without migration.

---

#### My question was closed.  What should I do now?

If the question is not on-topic on Stack Overflow:

- Determine if the question is better suited for [another site](https://stackexchange.com/sites).
- Before posting, please consult the Help Center section of the site to verify if your question is appropriate there.

Comment: Downvoted because of people being pedantic with "unique" ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357570/1394393), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330582/1394393), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366237/1394393)).

Comment: @jpmc26 and yet, that's the only thing that separates this site from other "programming" sites. Also, I'm pedantic with practical too.

Comment: I'm not going to waste my time trying to convince you of how wrong every part of that response is; we've been through it before. But the reasons why it's completely wrong can be found in the links for people who are actually interested.

Comment: One thing that occurs to me I didn't see in those links was instead of saying "unique to software development", perhaps say "specific to software development".  It still conveys that it needs to be strongly software development related, without implying that it cannot be also related to anything else.  I'm sure there are a number of things that should be on-topic for Stack Overflow also have applications outside of software development.

Comment: Also, as used in that sentence, I think "programming related" is more correct than "programming-related".

Comment: Perhaps "specific" instead of "unique"?

Comment: @M.Justin I suggested "strongly related" in the second link. None of the words or phrases seem perfect, though. The idea is that it's something that is part of the expertise acquired with experience doing software development.

Comment: @M.Justin here's the thing, we haven't need specific, but unique, to distinguish ourselves from other sites that are specific and practical to software development, like Software Engineering, Code Review, DevOps, Software QA, etc. Whiteboard issues aren't unique to software development, it's shared with other engineering tasks, so it's not unique. Quality or reviewing isn't unique either, it's basically universal. The whole thing is meant to be read as (practical software development ^ unique software development). We've (tried to) be that since inception.

Comment: @Braiam Wouldn't that mean that cross-cutting concerns couldn't be answered in any Stack Exchange site, assuming they all have a similar uniqueness requirement?

Comment: @M.Justin if none of the sites scopes apply, then yes. But I haven't seen that. This close reason only says that it doesn't fit our scope, it doesn't need other sites to exist, which is what the off topic meant at first.

Comment: @Braiam There is no need to "distinguish" Stack Overflow from other Stack Exchange sites. Having overlap between them is normal and accepted. Furthermore, SO has *never* been limited to problems that are *exclusively* within the software development field; there has always been some overlap with other relevant fields. "Unique" is a word with multiple definitions; it is not saying "exclusive."

Comment: @jpmc26 "has never been limited to problems that are exclusively within the software development field" well, it certainly hasn't kept itself in the same place: code golfing was moved to its own site, so was Software Engineering ([previously Programmers, previously NPR](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3412/)), Code Review, SU and SF (!), TeX, Recommend Things, etc. The scope of SO has been narrowing down to the definition I described, and I would like the momentum to continue and shed away topics that we aren't capable of answering with quailty.

Comment: @Braiam So maybe less about being unique to software development, and more about being part of software development and not in the domain of a more specialized Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @M.Justin again, SO doesn't need another SE site to exist to be off topic, same the opposite way, that is on topic on one site doesn't mean it's off topic on another. For example, creating a developer account on the Google Play console is something that is intrinsic to software development, it's still off topic because it's consumer support.

Comment: @Braiam There are definitely certain categories of things (consumer support, library recommendation questions, overly-broad asks, etc.) that are off-topic even though they otherwise fall in the "unique"/"specific" guidelines.  The "unique" vs. "specific" question doesn't affect those items, so I didn't bring it up.

Comment: @M.Justin not only certain categories: many categories. Heck, there are [categories for the categories](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417484/792066). Having a generic one will simply obsolete the need to type out any of those reasons. Also, remember it's two conditions are "unique" and "practical" to software development. Asking to create an account isn't unique, so I don't get why you say that it doesn't fail that test, as "how to create an account on X" is basically the same, follow X instructions.

Comment: @jpmc26 Maybe it's the dictionary I'm using, but I'm not seeing any definitions of "unique" that don't effectively mean "exclusive to".

Comment: @M.Justin I don't get the problem then? It has to be exclusive to software development, and a practical problem withing software development. That's exactly the definition I'm using. SO is at its best doing exactly that, everything else is basically a crapshot (if you ever had a sysadmin task, like configuring nginx for an app, you will notice that the recommendations are just "hacks", not professional or standard methods. This site is for programmers after all, which only preoccupation is that it works, not that it works well).

Comment: @Braiam Let me provide concrete examples. Questions on Git.  While it is _primarily_ used for software development, it can be used for any types of documents that need versioning (web sites, documents, etc.).  The general consensus seems to be that Git is on topic for Stack Overflow, but it is not _unique_ to software development, though it is primarily used for software development.  Similarly, questions on IDEs.  IDEs are primarily used in software development, but one could use an IDE to design a HTML-only website (something that is arguably not software).

Comment: @M.Justin https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unique 2b "Characteristic" is not the same thing as "exclusive." Not to mention 3. The point of this clause is not to try to make us argue over how a subject fits into a taxonomy. The point is to make sure the question is actually something that software development experts here are likely to have a significant body of expertise to bring to bear in writing an answer. The idea is that the subject matter should be *highly relevant* to software development.

Comment: @Braiam Programmers was created because the questions intended to go there were too subjective. Code Golf and Review and Recommendations contain questions where the *style* strongly clashed with the knowledge repository mission of SO. SU, SF, [dba.se], and [security.se] are subject matters where large swaths of devs lack basic competence in the subject. Most devs don't use TeX; it's mostly used for writing academic/research papers. Every one of your examples was created for reasons other than trying to narrow the subject matter of this site.

Comment: @jpmc26 and yet, some users on this site will try to push our scope to answering questions like those. As you said, those topics are where "large swaths of devs lack basic competence in the subject". So why not just remove it and do a favor for the rest of the internet by not showing our incompetence?

Comment: @Braiam Our scope is wide enough that we can handle simple questions in those fields, but the additional sites are necessary to cover a niche that software developers rarely can. SQL and other fairly basic database questions are *explicitly* on topic. Are you saying that software developers shouldn't ever answer SQL questions? The reason why we don't try to remove relevant topics is because it doesn't help anybody and wouldn't improve the quality of the site; it's pointless. If software devs frequently have the knowledge to answer a question, there is no harm in answering it here.

Comment: @jpmc26 2b is "distinctively characteristic", not just "characteristic"; i.e. a characteristic that distinguishes it from others, which effectively means "exclusive to".  3 doesn't work in the "unique _to_" sense used in this context, so that doesn't fit in the context used, though you're right that it doesn't mean "exclusive".

Comment: @M.Justin https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unique See the example usage in 4. The meaning in that definition is not as you interpret it; it's a much looser meaning than that.

Comment: @jpmc26 that SQL is a trick question? Writing SQL code is on topic here. Managing a SQL server should not be. Is not that hard a difference. There's some history I reference [on this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417008/overhauling-our-communitys-closure-reasons-and-guidance?cb=1#comment906919_417627) that you may find interesting and explains why it's like that. The whole time was about the _task_, not the tool that determined the scope of the site.

Comment: @Braiam SQL is on topic at DBA, too, and given their intimate knowledge of databases, they're likely to be better at it. Particularly when performance is a concern. And given that it's not really code that implements behaviors, but just a declaration of what data you want, why not make it off topic here? Many SQL queries will never find their way into a larger program, too. How is writing SQL "software development" but writing bash is not?

Comment: @jpmc26 That's the same meaning as dictionary definition 3 you already mentioned, and still does not work in the "unique to" sense.  You can say something  is unique (unusual) with that meaning, but you would never say it's "unique to" in that context ("unusual to" would actually have the opposite meaning: "swimming laps is unusual to software development" would say that you do not often see lap swimming practiced as part of software development).

Comment: @jpmc26 SQL code or SQL administrators? Remember, DBA means Database administrators and their scope, the only thing that is literally writing code is "Advanced Querying including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and query-performance". A SO user of basic sql, would be overwelmed there. They expect "**advanced** database-related questions". We seem to only expect english :)

Comment: Is [programming on a boat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about) programming-related?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn are you asking or just meme-ing? The answer is no, and the question you linked says so too.

Comment: @Braiam when I see "programming related", then I always think about that meme - because "programming-related" is a bit fuzzy.

Comment: @Braiam I don't think you realize you just admitted that something not exclusive to programming is on topic here and at another site. SQL queries are used by both devs and DBAs.

Comment: @jpmc26 Actually I admitted that something "exclusive to programming" being on topic here and elsewhere. Not the opposite. SO is still programming exclusive. Database administration is not programming.

Comment: @Braiam SQL queries are database administration. You can't divorce the two. [Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26489244/1394393) This particular example is also programming, since it's immensely useful in debugging deadlocks in an application and it finds uses in scripts. Not to mention more obvious examples like `CREATE TABLE`. Therefore, you did.

Comment: @jpmc26 what the actual heck? I can divorce the in a very simple way: privilege separation. Database administration implies creating tables, databases, starting/stopping the server, etc. Yes, a DBA can do queries, but that's not the only thing it does. I already agreed with that: you may need to create queries in your every day task to manage a database, but a programmer don't need to be able to turn on/off the server, deploy servers, have complete access to all performance metrics, etc. DBA's do need to. That's why DBA's give programmers a dev environment isolated from production.

Comment: @jpmc26 lets put it this way: who would you ask to know how to give minimal permissions to a third party piece of software to your databases? A DBA or a programmer?

Comment: @Braiam "Database administration implies creating tables, databases..." As a software developer/engineer working on developing a web application, I have written scripts to automate all those things. I have obtained, studied, and leveraged performance data. I have been heavily involved in not only planning, but executing the deployment of those applications and their databases. The same goes for privilege management as well. I've had a local database lock up, requiring me to restart the server. And if you think software devs never touch production environments, you're living in a fantasy.

Comment: @Braiam I wouldn't ask anyone how to "give minimal permissions to a third party piece of software." First, I'd be mad that the vendor is making me set up a user and privileges to begin with, rather than having something that automates that process. Then I'd ask the vendor what they support because no one else is going to know what is actually required. If I'm not confident that it's reasonable, I would ask someone who does work similar to what the software does whether that's really required and why (or maybe even ask the vendor why directly if it's crazy enough), which might be a dev.

Comment: @jpmc26 "As a software developer/engineer working on developing a web application, I have written scripts to automate all those things" yes! That's right, but you haven't had to do jack crap with "starting/stopping the server", deployment, configuring new servers, user permissions (in case auth/priv are centralized), deciding hardware configurations, having other applications on the same server, etc. System administrators have to juggle all those things that programmers do not need to. It's not your job as a software dev to do it. Now, if it's a small company you may be forced to do them all..

Comment: that doesn't mean that those are programming tasks either. I may have to do queries on a SQL server, but I'm not the system administrator of said servers, likewise I may use a Toyota but I'm not Japanese.

Comment: @Braiam "but you haven't had to do jack crap with 'starting/stopping the server', deployment, configuring new servers..." I literally described doing all those in my previous comment. Please read more carefully. A developer *must* develop expertise in such things because they impact your code directly, even in an environment where the duty is primarily someone else's. They must be accounted for in the application's design.

Comment: Also, nowhere does the site say "unique to programming." It says "unique to software development," which is a *much* broader statement even if you're going to be pedantic about it.

Comment: @jpmc26 "I literally described doing all those in my previous comment. Please read more carefully", no you described "I have written scripts to automate all those things" and quoted "creating tables, databases". So, yes, I read very carefully your comment, and found that you didn't. But lets presume that you did: how the actual heck you automate connecting to a server that may be either localhost or remote, that may use different authentication methods, that by either policy or administrative choice has to be a certain engine. As a software developer or programmer, you can't, as a sysadmin...

Comment: you should be able to. Programmers or software developer should not need to have access to production systems to do their job. Their job is to create programs using code. System administrators job is to manage the systems. That business decided to cut in cost and assign both task to the same person doesn't mean that they stopped being different. The worries of a system administrator or DBA's are totally different than a programmer. I hate when programmers suggest stuff that just because "works" (aka doesn't error out) it's a correct production environment.

Comment: @Braiam You apparently didn't read beyond the sentence you quoted because *that's* where I described the additional items. "...how the actual heck you automate connecting to a server that may be either localhost or remote, that may use different authentication methods, that by either policy or administrative choice has to be a certain engine." That is exactly what config management tools (e.g. Puppet, Chef, Ansible) do, by the way, although I wasn't using them at the time.

Comment: @Braiam "Their job is to create programs using code. System administrators job is to manage the systems. That business decided to cut in cost and assign both task to the same person doesn't mean that they stopped being different." In a shop that develops software, both their jobs are to work together to make the application perform its function. App developers need to understand how to use the platform they're building on, and sys admins need to understand what the developers are trying to accomplish. You *cannot* develop working software without everyone having some knowledge of both.

Comment: @Braiam The result of that necessity is that there is no clear cut line between two areas of expertise. They are intertwined, inseparable, and overlapping. You cannot understand how to write code effectively without understanding how the system will function, and you cannot administer the system effectively without understanding how the code will leverage it. The two fields are merely areas of *focus*, rather than exclusive knowledge bases, and the separate positions exist to ensure that the competing concerns are given due consideration, not to avoid learning about the other field.

Comment: @Braiam To clarify an earlier point: I did many of those tasks manually, and for deployment, some things were automated and some were manual instructions. But I still had to do them manually to test that they would work, and I was the most qualified person because I had the broadest understanding of what the application required. No sys admin had that knowledge of the app, only developers did. So I had to figure out how to modify the system to meet the app's requirements and how to change the app to meet the system's requirements. Neither of those is possible without knowledge of the system.

Comment: @jpmc26 and once you document those things, you can move to the next project and now system administrators can deploy new systems using your documentation. I'm not saying that programmers shouldn't know, it's that by that point it's not programming anymore.

Comment: @Braiam Nope. Has to be maintained. Kept up to date as the app changes, as new components are added or removed, as the system itself is updated, and as new requirements from system admins are added. And so do the scripts that automate much of the process. (Quite a few of my deployment instructions were simply "execute this script.") You never, ever stop dealing with system administration when developing software, and the tasks associated with application administration are getting more and more accessible via code all the time.

Answer (score 13):

#### Seeking recommendations

> **Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more**
> *This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.*

There are several things that could be improved in this one in addition to adding "tutorials."

- "and more" is useless text and really grinds my gears.  There are much better ways to word that.
- Requests for *official* documentation are allowed.  See [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic)
- It would be good to mention attracting spam as well as attracting opinions.

I'd recommend updating this to:

> **Seeking recommendations for 3rd-party resources**
> *Questions that ask for recommendations of non-official resources such as tools, books, software libraries, and tutorials are off-topic. Such questions are likely to attract spam and opinion-based answers.*

#### Needs debugging details

This close reason can be **removed**.  It is just a special case of "Needs detail or clarity." There is no need to take up a slot.

#### Not reproducible or was caused by a typo

"Not reproducible" is a special case of "Needs detail or clarity."  "Caused by a typo" is a subset of a bigger close reason: "Not useful to others" which I am adding below. This entire close reason should be **removed.**

#### Not about programming

I suggest that a new close reason should be for blatantly off topic questions. This can be a generic replacement for the Server Fault and Super User reasons.

> **Not about programming**
> This question is not about programming or programming tools. It could be edited to clarify how it relates to programming or asked on [another Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)

#### Not useful to others

I suggest that a new close reason should be about the utility of resource created by the question. This would replace the "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" reason as explained above.

> **Not useful to others**
> As currently written, this question will not be useful to others with similar problems. The goal of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of programming knowledge. Problems caused by typos or which are overly-specific to a unique situation are off-topic.

#### Needs customer support

I suggest that a new close reason be for [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow)

> **Needs customer support**
> Stack Overflow [cannot act as a customer support service on any company's behalf](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow). Rather than asking this question here, please contact the company or organization directly.

Comment: I think there used to be a "not useful to others" close reason years and years ago.

Comment: Indeed, it used to be called "too localized" and was apparently abused a lot as a subjective lever for closing questions. I don't necessarily agree that retiring it was the right thing to do, but that's my impression of why it no longer exists.

Comment: @tripleee IIRC, you are correct, that was the exact reason for retiring this. Although I'd much rather prefer it to be tweaked to eliminate the clairvoyance aspect of it to what we ended up with...

Answer (score 8):

Addressing the existing community-specific close reasons:

First of all, fix the grammar already! [Inconsistent conjunctions with new community close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396633/inconsistent-conjunctions-with-new-community-close-reasons) 
This has been reported over and over but it's still a mess. How hard can it be to fix basic grammar?

---

- > About general computing hardware and software

  This one isn't used a lot. It happens now and then, when someone is actually looking for generic PC help rather than programming. I don't think the close reason is particularly useful and can probably be removed.

  Especially since we already have: "This question belongs on another site in the network" -> superuser.com.

---

- > About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration

  I don't think I've ever used this one. It can be safely removed.

  (*Maybe* add "This question belongs on another site in the network" -> serverfault.com as an option, but again, this is such a rare close reason.)

---

- > Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more

  Frequently used, leave it as it is.

---

- > Needs debugging details

  Very frequently used.

  Though it got another one of those issues reported over and over, without anyone ever fixing it:
  [Put a direct link to the MCVE/MRE help page on the closure notice for "needs debugging details"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397048/put-a-direct-link-to-the-mcve-mre-help-page-on-the-closure-notice-for-needs-deb). 
  TL;DR: put the link to the minimal verifiable example help page back.

---

- > Not reproducible or was caused by a typo

  Frequently used, although I don't think it makes sense to have this as a single close reason. "Not reproducible" is a very different reason than "caused by a simple typo". I think this should be split in two different close reasons.

  Questions where the problem isn't reproducible need a clarification by the OP.

  Questions where the problem was caused by a simple, uninteresting typo just needs to be permanently closed/deleted and cannot be fixed by the OP or anyone else.

---

- > This question belongs on another site in the network

  Currently we have these options:

  - meta.stackoverflow.com
  - superuser.com
  - tex.stackexchange.com
  - dba.stackexchange.com
  - stats.stackexchange.com

  I'm probably biased like everyone else, depending on which tags I follow, but the only ones I have ever used are meta and Super User, and neither is commonly used. Sites that I refer people to with custom close reasons far more frequently are:

  - codereview.stackexchange.com
  - electronics.stackexchange.com

There are other sites I occasionally use too, but I'd like to add these two in particular to the current list. I'd say I use these a few times per month, whereas the meta and Super User close reasons are maybe used once per year at most.

Comment: The "belongs on another network" means "good enough to migrate," right? I think it would be nice if there was also at least something for, "This question is more likely to be answered on another Stack Exchange, but is not good enough to migrate." Kind of like the General Computing/Server-Networking one.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance I think you are looking for my proposed close reason that would replace those two. It should be used for questions that could be answered in another site, but it's not good enough as is to migrate.

Comment: For the questions I tend to see, Mathematics SE is the one I most frequently point people to.

Comment: Frequent use is at best a result of no better option, and should not be the sole reference for whether reasons are left intact. Almost all of the current close reasons contain multiple scenarios, and those need to be broken apart.

Comment: Did you not notice the "status-completed" tag on [that question you linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397048/put-a-direct-link-to-the-mcve-mre-help-page-on-the-closure-notice-for-needs-deb)? The MCVE/MRE help page is again linked in the closure banner for the "needs debugging details" reason. It has been back since I pestered Catija to do it back in October of 2021 and she stepped up immediately.

Comment: *"About general computing hardware and software / This one isn't used a lot."* - Citation needed. I use this *constantly*. We get many, many questions about general computing.

Comment: @RyanM is correct. "About general computing hardware and software" is [the 3rd most commonly used Community-Specific closure reason in the last 30 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YYQs.png). It's 6th overall (after Duplicate, Details or Clarity, Focus, Debugging Details, and Typo).

Comment: @RyanM Well, this is kind of subjective: depending on what tags you view you'll get different close reasons. However, when I used to hang out in the close vote review chat, I don't think that one was common either. If someone pulls out stats proving otherwise, then it should stay, obviously.

Comment: @Lundin is [15 742 requests](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cv-pls+general+computing&user=&room=90230) common enough for ya? :)

Comment: Going over the quote of @RyanM, if you take some of the well known tags, you can close them all with that reason, and you will not be wrong.

Comment: Regarding "Belongs to another site in the network": Maybe it would make sense to have an "other" option where one can fill in other sites (ideally some kind of a search list, like in "duplicate of", so I don't have to remember if it is "math", "maths" or "mathematics")

Comment: Try monitoring one of the cloud computing tags like `aws` and you will see that both of those "general computing" and "server admin" close reasons are used constantly! To be fair with all the "DevOps" stuff happening I think there is a ton of overlap between StackOverflow and ServerFault, and I often disagree when that close flag is used. It starts to feel like taxonomy for the same of taxonomy, just because programmers generally like organizing things, instead of a helpful action.

Comment: @MarkB yeah, like directing those that need a DBA towards the site where there are DBA's answering questions.

Comment: I don't find the 'belongs on another site' reason useful, not least because the sites that might be relevant to the questions I usually deal with are not on the list.  Either open up the list of sites to any that are programming/computing related, or drop the reason altogether.  I'd be happiest with a prioritized list of other sites (most likely first) rather than a simple alphabetic list, but I also recognize the inherent subjectivity of 'most likely'.  Maybe the top ten sites could be listed in priority order, and the remainder listed alphabetically, with a marker between the two parts?

Comment: @chtz: Mods of the site can migrate posts to any site, but regular users can only choose from the listed options (there can be a maximum of 5, I believe). If regular users want to suggest migrating to another site, they need to flag the post for mod attention. – In general, though, posts usually need a little editing to abide by the other site's rules/guidelines so it's sometimes better to just close the post (for not being suitable for the current site) and then encourage the user to post it to the other site themselves, after reviewing the other site's rules/guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

I would propose additional verbiage to

**4. Needs debugging details**

The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

One of the most ignored guidelines is supplying a minimal reproducible example, but another issue with this is the perennial "Here is my code: (in an image)", or "Here is my code: (Link to offsite repository)." These are two separate but related sub issues to "Needs debugging details".

In the first, the code exists, most likely, on Stack Overflow, but it cannot be copied and pasted, requiring anyone answering the question to retype everything correctly. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72012778/7129318)

In the second, the code can be manipulated, but it does not exist on Stack Overflow and therefore a deletion of the linked resource renders the question unintelligible to someone who is looking for answers to the same question. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72070486/7129318). (This question also falls under the heading of failed to research, as well.)

Of course, I am not arguing that images of code or offsite links are never appropriate, but only as supplements to the base minimal reproducible example. Good reasons would be showing the location of errors, showing tutorials followed as a basis of showing things tried, etc.

**My Proposal:**

Amend the language in the Usage Guidance to:

The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. *Images of code, or links to offsite repositories are not acceptable forms of posting the necessary code.*

Comment: **One of the most ignored guidelines is supplying a minimal reproducible example** - and I'd make a bet that newbies who include a minimal reproducible example have a better joining experience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the right place to suggest these is, but there are two close reasons (perhaps community-specific) that I'd love to see added:

- This is an obvious homework question showing no effort whatsoever, and we're not going to do your work for you.
- This question is so lame and/or incoherent that it's not worth trying to answer.

Obviously that second one would need to be much more nicely worded so as not to be "unwelcoming", but boy, do we get lots of questions from newbies who are, well, so clueless that they appear to require months of learning before they can even ask a sensible question.  (Sorry to be blunt; hope this doesn't count as being meta-unwelcoming.)

Comment: The first is an invalid close reason. The second is covered adequately by any reason that mentions the lack of clarity of the question, except for the "lame" part, which is also not ever a close reason. In general, you seem to be confusing closure with downvotes.

Comment: The thing about "lame" is that it is not an objective criterion that can be consistently applied as it is a function of expertise and interest - the higher the former and the lower the latter, the more likely you *personally* will consider a question as "lame". Close reasons, however, should not be dependent on experiences and preferences of the user voting to close - a question should be *objectively* lacking something (research [for dupes]; details; focus; clarity) to be eligible for closure.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for your comments.  I guess I need to continue my efforts to disassociate myself from this site, because I've voted to close *gobs* of questions for that first reason.  It's another clear indication that my attitudes are irreconcilably incompatible with SO's. (I say this without rancor.)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I suppose shouldn't have put that word "lame" in there; it's unnecessarily provocative.  Your points are well taken, although I personally feel that there are questions that are objectively so incoherent that they should be put out of their misery as soon as possible.  But I'm not going to press this point.

Comment: @SteveSummit oh, there definitely are, and a lot of them, I don't think we disagree here. Maybe it would be better to edit the answer to focus on the incoherent part? "lame" is, indeed, a trigger term implying subjective evaluation instead of objective analysis of the contents of the post.

Comment: We don't close questions because someone's asking about their homework. We close questions if they are off-topic (too broad, too many questions in one, etc). Usually a bad homework question will fall into that off-topic case. But this does not imply that all homework questions are off-topic.

Comment: @SteveSummit I phrased a suggestion as "Not a question but a copy/paste of a homework assignment." [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417627/584518). Seems to be the very same meaning as what you intended. Though this would specifically be about "copy/paste" scenarios - asking about homework is otherwise fine if the poster has put some effort into solving it themselves.

Comment: Or SO could go with the phrasing we picked for Codidact [here](https://software.codidact.com/help/on-topic): "Off-topic: Asking for implementations of a certain feature or a whole homework assignment. You should include your (partially working) attempts in the post". This also covers other "gimme teh codez" questions when the purpose isn't necessarily ones homework.

Comment: Please don't force people to add crappy partially working attempts. This only makes it more complicated to combine them as duplicates, be it for the same or similar tasks. Separating them all via the countless tiny mistakes that people make provides practically no benefit to the knowledge repository. Asking "how would I do <this>?" is perfectly fine by itself, trying to play whack a mole with illdefined requirements just whittles down curators.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If the requirements are off then the question should be closed as unclear, no matter if there's an attempt or not. Other than that, the purpose of forcing people to post their attempts is to filter out those who only wants their work done for them, with no intention of learning anything. Those who have a genuine interest in solving the problem has made some manner of attempt. Also, posting an incorrect attempt could illuminate the root of the problem - some misunderstanding that the OP got which prevents them from solving it correctly.

Comment: @Lundin I get where the sentiment is coming from, but I've seen it do more harm than good. Interesting and *generally useful* "how would one solve X" questions are sidelined as they get pushed to bland and niche "how would I fix X". By forcing questions to be about "their work", we also end up forcing questions to be about *doing their work* for them. Only now these questions are even less useful than if they had a hint of being general. You actually illustrate that by citing it as a *benefit* to illuminate "some misunderstanding that *the OP* got which prevents *them* from solving it".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Looking through the 30 or so most recent answers I've posted, roughly half of them are "almost correct but..." or "do like this instead" based on some code example by the OP. Most of these questions with code examples that I answered were of good or at least decent quality. If not for the code example, I might not have answered them. Related: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Lundin Looking through my most recent *not* answered questions... they would all have been "almost correct but..." or "do like this instead" based on some code example by the OP. Because they would have been of no benefit for practically anyone but the OP, who is likely the only one to do it almost correct in that specific way.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If the question is specific, then a partially working attempt should be useful. If it's not useful, the question is probably not specific enough (a "gimme teh codez" question)

Comment: @SteveSummit I am in full support of your wish for the first close reason (_"obvious homework question showing no effort whatsoever"_) to be added, though with less provocative wording. But I'm wondering what close reason do you use for such questions right now? Usually such questions are focused, clear and on topic, especially if they are a direct transcription of a homework assignment.

Comment: @skomisa In the past, I regularly closed them with a reason of "other", filling in "...because we are not going to do your homework for you" as the comment.  No one had ever complained about this, but when a mod with Cody's reputation tells me it's not a valid close reason here, I listen.  Thus my comment of Apr 24 at 13:45.

Comment: To be fair, @Steven, the *vast majority* of questions about homework on this site probably need to be closed. The nuance is that they aren't being closed because they are homework, nor because you subjectively feel that the asker didn't work hard enough on the problem themselves. Rather, they need to be closed because they fit into one of the existing close reasons, such as the question being too broad/lacking focus, and/or the question being unclear (e.g., because it lacks enough details/specifications, or because it's a work order not even a question), and/or because it's a dupe, etc.

Comment: The "how much research effort is expected" post is a great one, and I agree with nearly everything there, but those are recommendations/expectations directed at askers, not guidance for close-voters. A lack of research effort is enshrined as an officially-endorsed downvote reason (see the tooltip on the downvote arrow for a question), but it is not, in and of itself, a close reason. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909

Comment: @CodyGray how can then we tell askers that those kind of question are ones that we don't want asked or answered on the site? I agree with [Jeff on that sense](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/595/41104), since those kind of questions make answerers very unhappy (and here I use answerers to mean literally those that answer question with deep insight of the problem at hand, not merely "trying help"). If they don't answer questions (and SO has been bleeding those), the site continuous success is in jeopardy.

Comment: @SteveSummit I mean, Cody could be wrong too.

Answer (score -12):

### Bad motive

> The wording of the question looks like seeking something or solution that can be be used for some kind of inducement, deception or spying.
> For example: fake login interface, intrusion system, beyond authorization

In earlier, I have a question that may have been downvoted by the community by this reason(I guess).

Comment: This may be a valid reason to downvote, but we don't close questions on this basis. The intent/motivation of the asker is not relevant to whether a question is acceptable on this platform.

Comment: @CodyGray uh...well. it can be a reason of downvote, not a reason of close. But downvote is a reason of close. So it may actually is closed by bad motive, but no reason.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. What do you mean by "downvote is a reason of close"? Downvotes are not a reason to close a question. Downvoting and closing are two completely separate mechanisms. Both are a form of quality control, but downvoting merely expresses a user's subjective opinion that the question is unclear, uninteresting, and/or lacks research effort, where closure is an objective statement of fact that the question, as posed, is unsuitable on Stack Overflow and therefore should not be allowed to receive answers.

Comment: I am really uncomfortable with rating things as "evil". Something stereotypically bad like password cracking/sniffing/... can well be used to for vulnerability detection and prevention. Some well accepted practices like scraping or simply automation can do incredible harm by sheer volume and carelessness.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ok, let me change that discription. `Your quesion` -> `The wording of the question`

Comment: @CodyGray ok, I see now. Now I changed the discription of the "bad motive". What if the question reads as if the author intends to do some bad things??

Comment: "The intent/motivation of the asker is not relevant to whether a question is acceptable on this platform."

Comment: "bad motive" requires those with the CV/RV privilege to exercise clairvoyance. We do not have or intent to have such a close reason as intent is, indeed, irrelevant to a Q&A platform. If users believe the post is purposefully malicious, they can report the post via flagging, explaining in detail why they think it is made by a malicious actor. If your post was closed explicitly for the reason of *intent*, that was an incorrect closure (although I do not see any non-deleted recent posts by you that are closed because of that.